# Update Ubuntu MATE to 1.12

Tags: updates

At the moment I have Ubuntu MATE 1.11 but I can't find how to upgrade to desktop version 1.12.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question:  According to the [Ubuntu-Mate website](https://ubuntu-mate.org/wily/) you version number should look somethign like 15.04....

Comment: I gues the OP want's to update the version of MATE, not of the distribution.

Comment: True. I want to update to MATE desktop version 1.12 since I have 1.11. I have Ubuntu MATE 15.10. latest release

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions are available via the [**~ubuntu-mate-dev** PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mate-dev)

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/ppa
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/wily-mate
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends mate-desktop-environment
```

Comment: I now installed last line, and my graphic card is not detected anymore ....